# trying to use RAM configurator, what is my chipset?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I'm trying to use the [RAM Configurator](https://www.gskill.com/en/configurator?manu=54&chip=0&model=0) to detect settings for my ram (voltage and timing) but I have problems detecting my chipset in the list:

[image: Motherboard Specs]

Comment: It’s “Intel D3 DT x3 or x6 Slots X58” in the list. D3 means DDR3, DT means Desktop, the rest should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see where it says "Motherboard Chipset" in the pane on the right? The chipset is X58 + ICH10R.

*However*, the configurator you referred to wants you to select "Intel D3 DT x3 or x6 Slots X58" and then you will be able to select "GA-X58-USB3" in the next dropdown list.

It would be prudent to take the side off the case and have a look at the motherboard to confirm that it really is a GA-X58-USB3.

Comment: ICH10R is the southbridge. It’s not the “chipset”. The chipset is indeed called X58 *and ICH10R*.

Comment: thank you! How did you find the corresponding chipset in configurator?

Comment: @DanielB Does the processor now do the duty of the northbridge?

Comment: @S.Redrum I looked for one with X58. (Answer updated in the light of DanielB's comment.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Partly. Earlier, the northbridge contained the memory controller. It has since moved into the CPU. Northbridge and Southbridge are now typically combined. Wikipedia has [a section on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipset#Move_toward_processor_integration_in_PCs).

Comment: Since my RAM is missing from that congfigurator, is it safe to set BIOS voltage to 1,5V and 9-9-9-24 timing? Here are the [specs of my ram](http://imgur.com/a/J53ce)

Comment: @S.Redrum You have Kingston 9905403-083.A00LF RAM, so it is not surprising that you didn't find it on the G-Skill website. Yes, that voltage is safe. The timings depend on the speed the RAM is running at - the motherboard's auto setting for the RAM should take care of everything for you.

Comment: @AndrewMorton my problem is PC freezing after every first startup, after being off for the night, once it "heats-up" it works, googling I found that this issue is often caused by RAM voltage/timing, is it correct?

Comment: @S.Redrum If the RAM settings have not been changed then it is very unlikely to be the cause. The CMOS battery needing to be replaced is more likely in a motherboard of that age.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think I have replaced the battery a couple times since I purchased/repaired the PC, for the cost of a battery I'll give it a try, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @AndrewMorton this morning gave it a try and replaced the battery, no startup freezes and none so far! :)